# Use ShellExecute to browse to a \\location

Tags: c++builder, shellexecute

I use C++ with Borland C++ Builder and I am able to browse to a local or remote folder using the following code:

```
  AnsiString sDir = "C:\\Temp";
  ShellExecute(Application->Handle,"OPEN", "EXPLORER.EXE", sDir.c_str(), NULL, 1);
```

But if I try to access a folder on a remote computer that starts with two backslashes, such as "\\mypath", the above code does not work anymore. 
Is there a way to convince Windows Explorer open "\\mypath"?

Comment: What does *does not work anymore* mean exactly?

Comment: AnsiString sDir = "C:\\Temp\\"; ???

Comment: The location "C:\\Temp" is fine, I can open it in Windows Explorer. When I try to open "\\\\path", the program waits a long time, then it opens a different location, "Libraries". I tried path with two backslashes in front and also four backslashes and neither work.

Comment: That is a UNC file path and may take a few cycles to time out if it does not exist( or you don't have permission). Can you access the UNC path with a file browser?

Comment: Yes, I can open the location \\path manually using Windows Explorer. I can also access it by its IP Address, such as \\192.168.0.5, so if anybody has a solution on how to browse to an IP address with backslashes in front, that will also do

Comment: In Delphi there was at one point a function ExpandUNCFileName(). Is this not available for you?

Comment: Yes, I can use ExpandUNCFileName, but when I pass to it "\\mypath", it returns exactly the same thing... The path is a folder on a server, which I can access by server name or its IP Address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again the code I provided and in fact it works:

```
AnsiString sDir = "\\\\computername\\myfolder";
ShellExecute(Application->Handle,"OPEN", "EXPLORER.EXE", sDir.c_str(), NULL, 1);
```

I am not sure why it didn't work for me before (at one stage I probably forgot to use two backslashes in the path before myfolder, although I also tried accessing just computername). Sorry for wasting your time.

Nick

Comment: Then it is best if you delete your question before is is put on hold (closed).

Comment: I think the question is still useful, because somebody could learn of the need to use four backslashes and two backslashes (besides, StackOverflow recommends not to delete a question with answers).